# Javascript: Why can't I access the '../..' directory in browser on mac

Tags: javascript, html, windows, macos, browser

A client-side JS program includes the following lines:

```
<script src='../../LIBS/jwlib.js'></script>
<script src ='../js/header.js'></script>
<script src ='../js/session.js'></script>
<script src ='../js/classes.js'></script>
<script src ='../js/main.js'></script>
```

It runs properly on any browser under Windows.  But on my iMac it fails because it fails to find a function defined in jwlib.  And jwlib is not found by Chrome Developer Tools.

What's going wrong?

The program itself is at http://www.johnwheater.net/JAVASCRIPT/MULTIBODY/html/main.html

Thanks, Hugues and Chetan, for your interest. On loading, we should see a canvas with two squares, one blue and one black.  The blue one should show a collection of numbers between 1 and 50, and a button labelled BEGIN.  When you press that button the numbers should start dashing about.

This does not happen on my iMac, and Chrome Devtools reports a missing function get_random_integer().  If you put a breakpoint on line 366 of main.js you see the call, and the failure when you continue.

This function is in the file jwlib.js, which is not found.

I have made a new version, with the missing function pasted into main.js.  That is called MULTIBODY2 rather than MULTIBODY, and it works. as described.

Comment: How are you serving your file? are you just trying to open the .html file directly in the browser or are you using some kind of local server?  Please provide more information about your project.

Comment: Are you using a case sensitive file system?

Comment: are your work on simple html or use django or rubyonrails?

Comment: I ran `wget -p http://www.johnwheater.net/JAVASCRIPT/MULTIBODY/html/main.html` to fetch all these pages as they are, then opened "main.html" in Safari/Firefox/Chrome on MacOS, and it worked fine in all of them, with no missing resources.  Can you describe exactly what you're doing?  I don't think it has anything to do with '../..'

Comment: The program makes no reference at all to any server.  The browser loads the html from the server and the plain html runs as shown.

The point is, why does it run on Windows and not on mac.  Help!

Thanks Ssswift, did you run the program and see a lot of scattered numbers?  It doesn't work on my iMac, and the F12 shows it is not finding a function in jwlib.

Comment: I should make it clear that the page loads OK, but shows just a blank canvas.  It should show some scattered numbers and a 'begin' button.  You see this if you load it in Windows.

Chrome Developer tools on mac show that a function has failed to load, from a library specified in the html as ../..

Comment: There is no difference in behavior between Windows and Mac here (works fine on my mac). Main page is at `/JAVASCRIPT/MULTIBODY/html/main.html`, it loads several JS files from  `../../LIBS/*.js`, which are correctly found at `/JAVASCRIPT/LIBS/*.js`. What exactly is the error?

Comment: I'm using a Mac and I can see your output just fine. Maybe its not an OS issue

Comment: Thanks, Hugues and Chetan, for your interest.

Comment: Please see the newly edited question...

Comment: @JohnWhite After seeing your updated question, I went ahead to your website. Everything is working fine. (The game works also on both MULTIBODY and MULTIBODY2). I had no trouble in accessing jwlib.js either. Perhaps you are running this in a version control environment and there are different usages for production and local environments. If its in git you might also want to look at your gitignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the time wasting..

The problem is that I thought window.onload() would be called only when all the scripts had been loaded.

This seems not to be the case, and my problem was just a difference in timing between mac and windows.

Comment: But in the page, it seems like you are using body onload

Comment: Yes, thanks, Sagar, that was the fix, change window to body, and now there is no problem.

Comment: Please make a detailed answer for future visitors. or if you want, I can make one.

Comment: My ignorance of js was such that I thought that my

Answer (score 0):

I had a function init() which performed initialisation.  I nominated this to be called as  the window onload() function.

My ignorance of js was such that I thought that all files would be loaded by that time.

In fact, it is, I believe, the **body** onload event that signals the required condition.

When I changed to this,

```
<body onload = init()>
```

all was well on both OSX and Windows.  I guess therefore that my problem was caused by different load times in the two environments.